# Macro that creates a pivot table with changeable inputs?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I don't have a clue on where to start with this.
I very recently started using VBA to try and automate various processes in a spreadsheet I am working on at the moment. I effectively want to write a macro that takes data from one table and then removes all N/A points before outputting the data somewhere else. I then want it to do a simple linear regression on the data. My problem is that, at the start of the macro, I want to have various input boxes so the macro can create different tables based on the same data. For example if I had a table that lists costs of different fruits, their weights and number of calories, the macro could output a table that compares cost and weight or cost and calories depending on what the user wants. I also would like to be able to select where the data is output to.

I apologise for the lack of detail but I have spent an entire day scouring the internet for some kind of answer and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site. Please show some code of yours. It's pretty hard to help with so little details about the actual programming.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't Show much code, this is due to the sensitive nature of the project. I managed to get it working though so I suppose it doesn't matter any more :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove all N/A points, you want to:

clear active filters

filter out N/A

(You need to clear the active filters because Excel doesn't actually filter things out, it filters things IN.  If you set a filter and then add new data, it won't be in the set of filtered data)

Here is how I did it for a similar function:

```
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ECO - Project").ClearAllFilters
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ECO - Project")
        .PivotItems("00/01/00 ").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
```